# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{\displaystyle x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, contest-math

Evaluation of

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{\displaystyle x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Sis.

Comment: Do you really see integrals in high school?

Comment: @julien: what do you mean? Our high school books are full of limits, integrals and differential equations.

Comment: I don't know the US high school program. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @julien: are you a teacher?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am.

Comment: @julien: nice! Glad to hear that.

Comment: Yes, that's a great job. But except for Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, I have no idea about your integral, sorry. And I would be very surprised if it was taught in high school.

Comment: @julien: don't worry about that. I appreciate your feedback. You already provided with nice precious answers to my questions.(when that was possible) :)

Comment: Very informaly: $e^{x^n}$ can be made as close to $1$ as you like on any fixed interval $[0,1-\delta]$, $1>\delta>0$, Split the integral up into pieces: $\int_0^{1-\delta} f(x)\, dx+\int_{1-\delta}^1 f(x)\,dx$.  Show the left integral is close to $\pi/4$ and the right integral is close to $0$. Make things kosher with a limiting argument.

Comment: @DavidMitra: ops, I think I should try this. Thanks!

Comment: Julien, you people *don't* see integrals in high school? I find this surprising since, as far as I know, this is a must in most (sorry for the pun) more or less advanced countries. Of course, not integrals as the given one, which wouldn't even get, imo, into high school olympiads, but simple integrals of polynomial, rational, exponential, trigonometric, etc. functions, in particular to calculate geometric area...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I've seen integrals in high school. No such limit problems, though. Applications of the fundamental theorem of calculus, change of variable, integration by parts. My question was about the US high school program. I have taught Calculus I and Calculus II in US universities. And I had to teach derivatives and integrals from the very beginning, assuming that my students knew nothing about it. And indeed, it seemed completely new to most of them. So I took for granted, that they had not seen this before...I should have asked!

Comment: Well Julien, in fact and in general they don't see problems like this one...not even close, actually. What could be is some very special high school somewhere with a very special mathematics program, perhaps towards some university title. This kind of things exist in some countries, me thinks, but undoubtedly it is *not* regular high school stuff.

Comment: Our teacher says that this is one of the simplest problems ever. Actually, it's hard for me to say that I graduated from high school but not to know how to compute it (that's why I need elementary solutions). Moreover, I and my brother are self educated to some extent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic idea:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{\displaystyle x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{\displaystyle x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_0^1 \frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\displaystyle x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_0^1 \frac{e^{\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}x^{n}}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_0^1 \frac{e^{\displaystyle 0}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
$$ = {\pi \over 4}$$
Every step but the first is immediate or follows from continuity of an appropriate function. The first one is pretty standard (but not for high school students) since the integrands decrease in $n$. One way to prove it rigorously involves breaking the domain of integration into $[0,1-\epsilon]$ and $[\epsilon,1]$ parts. The second piece gives an integral less than $\epsilon$ for all $n$, and the integrands in the second converge uniformly (I know, not high school level but still) to ${1 \over 1 + x^2}$.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your work! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I'm might be missing something, but the integral is bounded by:
$$\int_0^1\frac{e}{1+x^2}dx > \int_0^1\frac{e^{x^n}}{1+x^2}dx > \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx$$
I think this is enough to interchange the limit with the integral due to the [Dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem), arriving at:
$$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \pi/4$$

Comment: Do they really know the Dominated convergence theorem in high school in the US ?

Comment: You don't need to mention the lower bound, do you?

Comment: @DamienL - they might just be ignoring it. I've seen high school teachers integrate $1/x$ from $-1$ to $1$..

Comment: @julien - yes, that's true.

Comment: @nbubis: thanks for your work (+1)